# Sorting List Items in LazyColumn - Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to implement a feature where the user is able to select a way to sort the list of Breweries when a certain item in a dropdown menu is selected (Name, City, Address). I am having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. Whenever I select example "Name" in the dropdown menu, the list of breweries does not sort. I am new at this so any advice will really help. Thank you!

Here is the full code for the MainScreen -

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel,
    search: String?
) {
    val apiData = brewData(mainViewModel = mainViewModel, search = search)



    Scaffold(
        content = {

            if (apiData.loading == true){
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(colorResource(id = R.color.grey_blue)),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator()
                }

            } else if (apiData.data != null){
                MainContent(bData = apiData.data!!, viewModel = mainViewModel)
            }
        },
        topBar = { BrewTopBar(navController, search) }
    )
}



@Composable
fun BrewTopBar(navController: NavController, search: String?) {
   TopAppBar(
       modifier = Modifier
           .height(55.dp)
           .fillMaxWidth(),
        title = {
            Text(
                stringResource(id = R.string.main_title),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        },
        actions = {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Text(text = "$search")
                IconButton(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screens.SearchScreen.name) }) {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search,
                        contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.search)
                    )
                }
            }

        },
       backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.light_purple)
    )
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun MainContent(bData: List<BrewData>, viewModel: MainViewModel){

    val allBreweries = bData.size
    var sortByName by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var sortByCity by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var sortByAddress by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var dataSorted1 = remember { mutableStateOf(bData.sortedBy { it.name }) }
    var dataSorted: MutableState<List<BrewData>>

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colorResource(id = R.color.grey_blue))
    ){

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){
            // Amount text label
            Text(
                text = "Result(s): ${bData.size}",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp, start = 15.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
            )
            SortingMenu(sortByName, sortByCity, sortByAddress) // needs mutable booleans for sorting
        }

        // List of Brewery cards
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(5.dp)
        ){
            items(allBreweries){ index ->
                Breweries(
                    bData = when {
                        sortByName == true -> remember { mutableStateOf(bData.sortedBy { it.name }) }
                        sortByCity == true ->  remember { mutableStateOf(bData.sortedBy { it.city }) }
                        sortByAddress == true -> remember { mutableStateOf(bData.sortedBy { it.address_2 }) }
                        else -> remember { mutableStateOf(bData) }
                    } as MutableState<List<BrewData>>, // Todo: create a way to select different sorting conditions
                    position = index,
                    viewModel = viewModel
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun Breweries(
    bData: MutableState<List<BrewData>>,
    position: Int,
    viewModel: MainViewModel
){

    val cardNumber = position+1
    val cityApiData = bData.value[position].city
    val phoneNumberApiData = bData.value[position].phone
    val countryApiData = bData.value[position].country
    val breweryTypeApiData = bData.value[position].brewery_type
    val countyApiData = bData.value[position].county_province
    val postalCodeApiData = bData.value[position].postal_code
    val stateApiData = bData.value[position].state
    val streetApiData = bData.value[position].street
    val apiLastUpdated = bData.value[position].updated_at

    val context = LocalContext.current
    val lastUpdated = apiLastUpdated?.let { viewModel.dateTextConverter(it) }
    val websiteUrlApiData = bData.value[position].website_url
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    val clickableWebsiteText = buildAnnotatedString {
        if (websiteUrlApiData != null) {
            append(websiteUrlApiData)
        }
    }
    val clickablePhoneNumberText = buildAnnotatedString {
        if (phoneNumberApiData != null){
            append(phoneNumberApiData)
        }
    }

    Column(
        Modifier.padding(10.dp)
    ) {

        //Brewery Card
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp)
                // .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable(
                    enabled = true,
                    onClickLabel = "Expand to view details",
                    onClick = { expanded = !expanded }
                )
                .semantics { contentDescription = "Brewery Card" },
            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.light_blue),
            contentColor = Color.Black,
            border = BorderStroke(0.5.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.pink)),
            elevation = 15.dp

        ) {

            Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {

                //Number text for position of card
                Text(
                    text = cardNumber.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp),
                    fontSize = 10.sp,
                )

                // Second Row
                BreweryTitle(bData = bData, position = position)

                // Third Row
                // Brewery Details
                CardDetails(
                    cityApiData = cityApiData,
                    stateApiData = stateApiData,
                    streetApiData = streetApiData,
                    countryApiData = countryApiData,
                    countyApiData = countyApiData,
                    postalCodeApiData = postalCodeApiData,
                    breweryTypeApiData = breweryTypeApiData,
                    lastUpdated = lastUpdated,
                    expanded = expanded
                )

                //Fourth Row
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ){

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(
                            start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp,
                            top = 15.dp, bottom = 15.dp
                        ),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {

                        //Phone Number Link
                        LinkBuilder(
                            clickablePhoneNumberText,
                            phoneNumberApiData,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                        ) {
                            if (phoneNumberApiData != null) {
                                viewModel.callNumber(phoneNumberApiData, context)
                            }
                        }
                        //Website Link
                        LinkBuilder(
                            clickableWebsiteText,
                            websiteUrlApiData,
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 15.dp),
                            intentCall = {
                                if (websiteUrlApiData != null) {
                                    viewModel.openWebsite(websiteUrlApiData, context)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CardDetails(
    cityApiData: String?,
    stateApiData: String?,
    streetApiData: String?,
    countryApiData: String?,
    countyApiData: String?,
    postalCodeApiData: String?,
    breweryTypeApiData: String?,
    lastUpdated: String?,
    expanded: Boolean
){
    // Third Row
    //Brewery Details
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            start = 30.dp, end = 10.dp, top = 25.dp, bottom = 15.dp
        ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        if (expanded) {
            Text(text = "City:  $cityApiData")
            Text(text = "State:  $stateApiData")
            Text(text = "Street:  $streetApiData")
            Text(text = "Country:  $countryApiData")
            Text(text = "County:  $countyApiData")
            Text(text = "Postal Code:  $postalCodeApiData")
            Text(text = "Type:  $breweryTypeApiData")
            Text(text = "Last updated:  $lastUpdated")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BreweryTitle(bData: MutableState<List<BrewData>>, position: Int){
    // Second Row

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {

            // Name of Brewery
            Text(
                text = bData.value[position].name!!,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                maxLines = 3,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                softWrap = true,
                style = TextStyle(
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_500),
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
                    fontSize = 17.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    letterSpacing = 2.sp,
                )

            )
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun LinkBuilder(
    clickableText: AnnotatedString,
    dataText: String?,
    modifier: Modifier,
    intentCall: (String?) -> Unit
){
    if (dataText != null){
        ClickableText(
            text = clickableText,
            modifier = modifier,
            style = TextStyle(
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
                letterSpacing = 2.sp
            ),
            onClick = {
                intentCall(dataText)
            }
        )
    }
    else {
        Text(
            text = "Sorry, Not Available",
            color = Color.Gray,
            fontSize = 10.sp
        )
    }
}

//Gets data from view model
@Composable
fun brewData(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel, search: String?
): DataOrException<List<BrewData>, Boolean, Exception> {

    return produceState<DataOrException<List<BrewData>, Boolean, Exception>>(
        initialValue = DataOrException(loading = true)
    ) {
        value = mainViewModel.getData(search)
    }.value
}


@Composable
fun SortingMenu(sortByName: Boolean, sortByCity: Boolean, sortByAddress: Boolean,) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val items = listOf("Name", "City", "Address")
    val disabledValue = "B"
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Sort by: ${items[selectedIndex]}",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true })
                .width(120.dp)
        )
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false // todo: sort list data when clicked
                when(selectedIndex){
                    0 -> sortByName == true
                    1 -> sortByCity == true
                    2 -> sortByAddress == true
                } }
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedIndex = index
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    val disabledText = if (text == disabledValue) {
                        " (Disabled)"
                    } else {
                        ""
                    }
                    Text(text = text + disabledText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//not used
fun sorting(menuList: List<String>, dataList: List<BrewData>, index: Int){
    when{
        menuList[index] == "Name" -> dataList.sortedBy { it.name }
        menuList[index] == "City" -> dataList.sortedBy { it.city }
        menuList[index] == "Address" -> dataList.sortedBy { it.address_2 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you to everyone that has helped me with this issue. I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Comparator`and `Modifier.animateItemPlacement()` so it would look even nicer!

I will post an example from Google so you can understand the logic:

```
@Preview
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PopularBooksDemo() {
    MaterialTheme {
        var comparator by remember { mutableStateOf(TitleComparator) }
        Column {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    "Title",
                    Modifier.clickable { comparator = TitleComparator }
                        .weight(5f)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Text(
                    "Author",
                    Modifier.clickable { comparator = AuthorComparator }
                        .weight(2f)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Text(
                    "Year",
                    Modifier.clickable { comparator = YearComparator }
                        .width(50.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
                Text(
                    "Sales (M)",
                    Modifier.clickable { comparator = SalesComparator }
                        .width(65.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                )
            }
            Divider(color = Color.LightGray, thickness = Dp.Hairline)
            LazyColumn(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
            ) {
                val sortedList = PopularBooksList.sortedWith(comparator)
                items(sortedList, key = { it.title }) {
                    Row(
                        Modifier.animateItemPlacement()
                            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            it.title,
                            Modifier.weight(5f)
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                        Text(
                            it.author,
                            Modifier.weight(2f)
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                        Text(
                            "${it.published}",
                            Modifier.width(55.dp)
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                        Text(
                            "${it.salesInMillions}",
                            Modifier.width(65.dp)
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(4.dp)
                                .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private val TitleComparator = Comparator<Book> { left, right ->
    left.title.compareTo(right.title)
}

private val AuthorComparator = Comparator<Book> { left, right ->
    left.author.compareTo(right.author)
}

private val YearComparator = Comparator<Book> { left, right ->
    right.published.compareTo(left.published)
}

private val SalesComparator = Comparator<Book> { left, right ->
    right.salesInMillions.compareTo(left.salesInMillions)
}

private val PopularBooksList = listOf(
    Book("The Hobbit", "J. R. R. Tolkien", 1937, 140),
    Book("Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "J. K. Rowling", 1997, 120),
    Book("Dream of the Red Chamber", "Cao Xueqin", 1800, 100),
    Book("And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", 1939, 100),
    Book("The Little Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", 1943, 100),
    Book("The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe", "C. S. Lewis", 1950, 85),
    Book("The Adventures of Pinocchio", "Carlo Collodi", 1881, 80),
    Book("The Da Vinci Code", "Dan Brown", 2003, 80),
    Book("Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets", "J. K. Rowling", 1998, 77),
    Book("The Alchemist", "Paulo Coelho", 1988, 65),
    Book("Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban", "J. K. Rowling", 1999, 65),
    Book("Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire", "J. K. Rowling", 2000, 65),
    Book("Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "J. K. Rowling", 2003, 65)
)

private class Book(
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val published: Int,
    val salesInMillions: Int
)
```

Comment: This is a TERRIBLE answer. Don't do that. You should instead tell a ViewModel the change in selection and have the ViewModel update comparator and re-sort the list off the main thread

Comment: @DanieleSegato I didn't say anything that this is a best practice in order to handle heavy CPU tasks. It is a quick example that shows how to utilize `animateItemPlacement()` with `comparator` in order to get an ordered list with animation. Simple as that...

Comment: Still terrible. People will copy this thinking it's OK, just cause they don't know better. Your answer is even "accepted answer". Which makes it worse. The sorting here is re-executed at every recomposition on the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

It's really difficult to track this much code especially on my 13 inch screen.

You should move your sort logic to ViewModel or useCase and create a sort function you can call on user interaction such as `viewmodel.sort(sortType)` and update value of one `MutableState` with new  or use mutableStateListOf and update with sorted list.

Sorting is business logic and i would do it in a class that doesn't contain any Android related dependencies, i use MVI or MVVM so my preference is a UseCase class which i can unit test sorting with any type and a sample list and desired outcomes.

Answer (score 1):

You have tons of codes and I only see `lists`, so its hard to guess what's going on, but based on

> the list of breweries does not sort

I would advice creating a very simple working app with 1 `data class` 1 `Viewmodel` 1 `Screen` with a `LazyColumn` and 1 `Button`.

Consider this:

Your `data class`

```
data class Person(
   val id: Int,
   val name: String
)
```

Your `ViewModel`

```
class MyViewModel {
    val peopleList = mutableStateListOf<Person>() // SnapshotStateList
    
    fun onSortButtonClicked() {
         // do your sorting logic here 
         // update your mutable`State`List
    }
}
```

Your `Composable` Screen

```
@Composable // I just put the view model as an argument, don't follow it  you don't need to
fun MyScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
      val myList = viewModel.peopleList

       LazyColumn {
           items(items = myList, key = { person -> person.id }) { person ->
              //.. your item composable //
       }

       Button(
           onClick = { viewModel.onSortButtonClicked() }
       )
   }
}
```

It works but its not advisable to use `MutableList` inside a `State` or `mutableState` as any changes you make on its elements won't trigger `re-composition`, your best way to do it is to `manually copy` the entire `List` and create a new one which is again not advisable, thats why `SnapshotStateList<T>` or `mutableStateListOf<T>` is `not only recommended` but the only way to deal with `lists` in `Jetpack Compose` development efficiently.

Using `SnapshotStateList`, any updates (in my experience) such as `deleting` an element, `modifying` by doing `.copy(..)` and re-inserting to the same index will guarantee a `re-composition` on a `Composable` that reads that element, in the case of the "working sample code", if I change the name of a person  in the `SnapshotStateList` like `peopleList[index] = person.copy(name="Mr Person")`, the `item` `composable` that reads that person object will `re-compose`. As for your `Sorting` problem, I haven't tried it yet so I'm not sure, but I think the list will sort if you simply perform a sorting operation in the `SnapshotStateList`.

Take everything I said with the grain of salt, though I'm confident with the usage of the `SnapshotStateList` for the "working sample code", however there are tons of nuances and things happening under the hood that I'm careful not to just simply throw around, but as you said

> I am new at this

So am I. I'm confident this is a good starting point dealing with `collections`/`list` in jetpack compose.

Comment: thank you for this very detailed advice! I will try this out I'm sure this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this when I need to

```
package com.example

import androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp

private class User(
    val name: String,
    val city: String,
    val address: String,
    val addressNumber: Int
)

private val UsersList = mutableStateListOf(
    User(name = "Michael", city = "New York", address = "x street", addressNumber = 1234),
    User("Jorge", "Los Angeles", "street A", 2743),
    User("Adam", "Chicago", "street B", 3045),
    User("Philip", "Houston", "street C", 4432),
    User("Amanda", "Phoenix", "street D", 567),
    User("Madonna", "Philadelphia", "street E", 6834),
    User("Jordan", "San Antonio", "street F", 792),
    User("Jackson", "Some City", "street G", 802),
    User("Potter", "Dallas", "street H", 99),
    User("Harry", "Austin", "street I", 161),
    User("Cruise", "San Francisco", "street J", 1732),
    User("Denzel", "Seattle", "street K", 1743),
    User("Hermione", "Denver", "street L", 134),
    User("Vin Diesel", "Dallas", "street M", 134)
)

@Composable
fun SortScreen() {
    val listSorted = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<User>()
    }
    listSorted.addAll(UsersList)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
        content = {
            Text(
                text = "${UsersList.size} Users",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 25.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                )
            )
            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                content = {
                    Button(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                        border = BorderStroke(4.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
                        onClick = {
                            listSorted.clear()
                            listSorted.addAll(UsersList.sortedBy { it.name })
                        },
                        content = {
                            Text(
                                text = "Sort by Name",
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                    Button(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                        border = BorderStroke(4.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
                        onClick = {
                            listSorted.clear()
                            listSorted.addAll(UsersList.sortedBy { it.city })
                        },
                        content = {
                            Text(
                                text = "Sort by City",
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                    Button(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                        border = BorderStroke(4.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
                        onClick = {
                            listSorted.clear()
                            listSorted.addAll(UsersList.sortedBy { it.address })
                        },
                        content = {
                            Text(
                                text = "Sort by Address",
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                    Button(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                        border = BorderStroke(4.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer),
                        onClick = {
                            listSorted.clear()
                            listSorted.addAll(UsersList.sortedBy { it.addressNumber })
                        },
                        content = {
                            Text(
                                text = "Sort by AddressNumber",
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                content = {
                    itemsIndexed(listSorted) { index, data ->
                        Card(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                                .padding(10.dp)
                                .clickable {

                                },
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(4.dp),
                            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                            border = BorderStroke(
                                4.dp,
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer
                            ),
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Position: $index",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "Name: ${data.name}",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "City: ${data.city}",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 17.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                )
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "Address: ${data.address}: ${data.addressNumber}",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(5.dp),
                                style = TextStyle(
                                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

[image]